# Spring jpa interceptor for derived queries

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, interceptor

I want to intercept spring jpa derived queries before execution. i tried with EmptyInterceptor and StatementInspector, but they are intercepting queries annotated with @query.

Comment: Could you please describe the initial problem that you try to solve?

Comment: i have multiple schemas for test/ dev, i want to intercept query and read schema from props and update query with respective schema.

Comment: Don't... Specify the schema you want to use through the `hibernate.default_schema` property. You can set that using spring profiles with a specific `application-<profile>`.properties` file. Don't try to mess around with an interceptor.

Comment: with default schema you can specify only one schema, i have multiple schemas for single env.

Answer (score 1):

I reccommend the net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:

```
implementation 'net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:1.5.1'
```

Here is the PostProcessor & Interceptor:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DatasourceProxyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
    if (bean instanceof DataSource && !(bean instanceof ProxyDataSource)) {
      log.info("DataSource bean has been found: " + bean);
      final ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
      factory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
      factory.addAdvice(new ProxyDataSourceInterceptor((DataSource) bean));
      return factory.getProxy();
    }
    return bean;
  }

 @Override
 public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
   return bean;
 }

 private static class ProxyDataSourceInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
   private final DataSource dataSource;

    public ProxyDataSourceInterceptor(final DataSource dataSource) {
     this.dataSource = ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(dataSource)
      .name("MyServiceDS")
      .logQueryBySlf4j(SLF4JLogLevel.DEBUG)
      .multiline()
      .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      final Method proxyMethod = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(this.dataSource.getClass(),
          invocation.getMethod().getName());
      if (proxyMethod != null) {
        return proxyMethod.invoke(this.dataSource, invocation.getArguments());
      }
      return invocation.proceed();
    }

  }
}
```

For more Informations: https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy